# differentiating a smooth function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose we define a function by the integral $$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y) dy $$Suppose we know that $f(x)$ is smooth. Does this mean that necessarily $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y) dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \partial_x g(x,y) dy $$ ?

I know that in general to move the derivative under the integral sign we need the partial derivative to be absolutely integrable. But what if we know that $f(x)$  is differentiable?

Comment: Is $g$ absolutely integrable in both variables? Is is absolutely integrable in $y$ for each fixed $x$?

Comment: We don't know about $g$ (because I am ultimately trying to show something about it). I am wondering if there are conditions on $f$ which allow us to necessarily differentiate under the integral.. if smoothness is not enough perhaps some growth conditions on $f$ (for example that it is a Schwartz function).

Comment: Well, choose your favourite $f$. Then, for each $x$ take some function (in $y$) whose integral is equal to $f(x)$.
These functions for different $x$ may be unrelated, so $g$ made from gluing them would not be continuous, let alone smooth. So in this case $\partial_xg$ is not even defined.

Comment: My bad, $g$ is smooth in both $x$ and $y$. We don't know about it's absolute integrability I meant. But we know it is smooth.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. But then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x,y)dy$ is defined as $\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{-T}^Tg(x,y)dy$? And is $g$ at least bounded?

Comment: My goal is to show that any arbitrary number of $x$ derivatives of $g$ is absolutely integrable in $y$. We know if the derivatives are absolutely integrable then we can differentiate under the integral. I was hoping to use the reverse though come to think of it, I am not sure the reverse is even true - that being allowed to differentiate under the integral sign would imply absolute integrability of the derivatives...